# Warning with gedit in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I keep getting this irritating warning when i open a file with gedit in the background in the Ubuntu terminal

GLib-GIO-WARNING **: FAMOpen failed, FAMErrno=0

It doesn't hamper me in any way, but it'd be nice not to see the warning message all the time. anyone help me in doing away with it?

Answer (score 0):

Install the fam package.

sudo apt-get install fam

Answer (score 0):

Install fam package as described above and look with

```
/etc/init.d/fam status
```

whether or not the service runs. Start the service with

```
/etc/init.d/fam start
```

and the warning should not longer occur (tested on openSUSE 12.1).